# Make www-data the owner and group of newly created files and folders

Tags: permissions, access-control-list, setfacl

I am running **Ubuntu 16.04**.

I have several users that are within the **www-data** group and will be creating/modifying files on the server.

We'll call them **user1** and **user2**.

Any time **user1** or **user2** creates a folder or file within `/var/www/sites/domain1.com/public` I would like the owner and group to default to **www-data**.
I would like the files to have the permissions of **0664** and the folders to have the permissions of **0775**.

So lets say user1 is logged in and creates a file called `test-file.txt`

If I run:

`ls -l on /var/www/sites/domain1.com/public`

I would like the output to look like:

`-rw-rw-r-- www-data www-data test-file.txt`

I believe this can be done with `setfacl`, but am not quite sure what the command would be or if there is a better way.

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/odd.blog/2013/11/05/fix-file-644-directory-775-permissions-linux-easily/amp/ will help you

Answer (score 2):

Changing the directory permissions from **0775** to **2775** would give you most of what you ask for. The **2** means **set group ID** and when used on a directory means that new objects created within that directory will inherit the group of the directory rather than getting the current group of the process which created the object.

If the directories are not already owned by group **www-data** you need to change the group first before changing permissions.

Additionally you need to ensure that the umask of each user is **0002**. that is the default so unless the users have changed it will already have the correct value.

Doing the above covers everything you asked for except from changing the owner of the files. I haven't come across usage scenarios where that difference was important, and having the owner of a file indicate who created the file can be useful.

A completely different approach would be to use a source control system and create a procedure for pushing updates of the files from source control. Using source control is a major help when multiple people need to update the same files.

Comment: I ran a `sudo chmod 2755 -R /var/www/sites/domain1.com/public`, but that now doesn't let me add files/folders unless I use the sudo command. Was there a different way I should be doing this? Plus I wanted only folders to have 775 and files to have 664. Thanks

Comment: @bigmike7801 I said **2775** not **2755**. Also I only said to change it on directories not files. The files should remain **0664**.

Comment: sorry I fat-fingered the "2775".

Comment: @bigmike7801 Did you ensure the directories had correct group before using `chmod`?

Comment: Yes, they're good now.

Comment: @bigmike7801 Notice they are called **directories** and not "folders", a Windows-ism.

Comment: Six of one, half a dozen of the other...